# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'?

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unable to read FCM notification Userdata, I am trying this-

```
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

             if let jsonResult = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> //**Getting error on this line**
{

             if let notifyType = 
              jsonResult["gcm.notification.notification_type"] as? String ?? "" 
              {

                print(notifyType)           

              }
            }
```

Comment: on which line the error is there?

Comment: @iDeveloper you must have to also show your JSON response.Please edit your question

Comment: Some side note: if let X means conditional binding if the rightside is optional. Since you used ... ?? "", it means you already provide a default value when the value is nil, which means it isn't an optional value. If let X is therefore unvalid.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks for the deep description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code
replace:

```
  if let notifyType = 
      jsonResult["gcm.notification.notification_type"] as? String ?? "" 
      {
```

with:

```
  if let notifyType = 
      jsonResult["gcm.notification.notification_type"] as? String {
```